# Excel - Is there a text delimiter other than " which I can use when manipulating text in an IF statement?

Tags: json, excel, excel-formula

I'm attempting to produce a spreadsheet which will produce a formatted json string within a cell which can then be copied and pasted out into another application.

My problem is pretty simple, the json record contains lots of " characters delimiting the variable names and associated values in the json string.

I want to manipulate the value strings in the json using IF statements to generate test data.

Is there a way to alter the text delimiter within the worksheet to allow me to use something other than " in the IF formula without affecting:

- Excel as a whole
- The validity of the IF formula as a whole

Please note that I need to do this via a formula in a cell (or cells), not via VBA. We have system restrictions preventing macros, etc being run which negates that approach.

Thoughts appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Will [Substitute](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUBSTITUTE-function-6434944e-a904-4336-a9b0-1e58df3bc332) function work? ... `Substitute(A1,""",",")` for example

Comment: Unfortunately not Scott. The json record is pretty complex and I need to use a nested if with multiple insertions of data in the resulting output of the formulae. The substitution would potentially introduce too many additional errors.